# Filtering web.xml when using the jetty-maven-plugin?

Tags: jakarta-ee, maven, web.xml, maven-jetty-plugin

**Original Post:**
I want to filter the `web.xml` deployment descriptor of a Java 6 web application which is running on the Jetty 8.1 servlet container, but it does not work so far. I want to set a different JSF project stage depending on the active maven profile:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>${jsfProjectStage}</param-value>
</context-param>
```

The profiles section in the `pom.xml` looks like that:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>development</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <jsfProjectStage>Development</jsfProjectStage>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>production</id>
        <properties>
            <jsfProjectStage>Production</jsfProjectStage>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

On the internet you find several ways to accomplish that, e.g. using alternative web.xml files. But to me the most obvious way seems to use the maven-war-plugin:

```
<build>
    <finalName>...</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <webResources>
                    <webResource>
                        <directory>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                        <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
                        <includes>
                            <include>web.xml</include>
                        </includes>
                    </webResource>
                </webResources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        ...

    </plugins>
</build>
```

Since you find many answers or articles with this code snippet, I wonder why it is not working for me. I tried to replace `<webResource>` with `<resource>` (often found it this way) and I also tried to add `<filteringDeploymentDescriptors>true</filteringDeploymentDescriptors>` but nothing of that works.

Does anyone have an idea, what is missing here in order to filter the web.xml correctly? Or do I have to explicitly specify `<filters>`?

Thanks
Sebastian

**Update:**
Thanks to *user944849* I know now that the reason for my not filtered `web.xml` is not the maven-war-plugin but the jetty-maven-plugin, since I use `mvn jetty:run` to run the (unassembled) webapp. Does anyone know how to bring the jetty-maven-plugin to filter the `web.xml` before running the unassembled webapp?

Comment: What is your maven command?  In particular, how are you activating the profile? `<activeByDefault>` means "active only if no other profile is active."

Comment: I use Maven from within Eclipse and the _Goals_ for my _Run Configuration_ for the development build is set to `clean jetty:run` with no explicit _Profiles_ set. The Goal for the production build is set to `clean install` with the _Profiles_ set to `production`.

Comment: Does the production one filter the web.xml as you'd expect?  It doesn't surprise me at all that `jetty:run` doesn't work, as `jetty:run` executes an _unassembled_ webapp.  Filtering happens when the war plugin is run as part of the package phase, which `jetty:run` doesn't use IIRC.  You probably need to do a little research to figure out how to make jetty do the filtering.  Or, you may need to use jetty against a fully assembled webapp.

Comment: Yes, you're right! When building for production, the assembled webapp contains a filtered `web.xml`. I just needed to set `filteringDeploymentDescriptor` to true in order to achieve this. Honestly, I didn't tried building for production before.
So now I just have to figure out, how to enable web.xml filtering for the jetty-maven-plugin. Thanks so far

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After figuring out that the problem was not the maven-war-plugin but the jetty-maven-plugin, I just had to change the maven command from `mvn clean jetty:run` to `mvn clean jetty:run-war` in order to run an assembled webapp on the embedded jetty in which the deployment descriptor gets also filtered.

Thanks for your help guys
Sebastian

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration seems correct, but in my experience you may need also `<filters>` section.

For example, my application has something similar to:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-war-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                <webResources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/bm.js</include>
                        </includes>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>
                <warName>${war.name}</warName>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <filters>
        <filter>src/main/filters/filter-${target.environment}.properties</filter>
    </filters>
</build>
```

The `bm.js` file contains a reference to a macro `${my.property}`, which value is set in 2 different files, `filter-dev.properties` and `filter-qa.properties`. I do have 2 different maven profiles (called `dev` and `qa`) in the parent POM in which I define the `target.environment` property accordingly.

When running `mvn package` specifying the profile, the macro in `bm.js` will be replaced with the correct value.

I'm not 100% sure this would necessary work with `web.xml`, but you can give it a try.

Comment: It somehow don't make sense to use an extra filter file, since the new value (after the replacement) comes from a Maven profile properties variable in the `pom.xml`. Nevertheless I tried it and it still doesn't filter anything in `web.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

Just my 2 cents:

Using *run-war* is a bit worse than using *run*, as the *run-war* will require packaging -- not handy for development.  Solution that worked for me is to follow those steps (I can imagine a more simple one, but we have several tweeks in maven and project deployment):

1. Leave default webapp resource filtering as is and add our own, custom filtering
2. Point jetty config to custom docroot (and alternate web.xml)
3. Bind jetty to prepare-package (maven 2.2.1+) phase as the last phase before actual packaging
4. Once done, one can simply run maven and provide the properties at command line, st. like: `mvn -Djetty=run -Djetty.webcontext=any-web-context -Djetty.port=8180 prepare-package`

Config below is for maven2, but modification for new org.eclipse.jetty & maven3 should be straightforward:

```
    <!-- jetty:run -->
    <profile>
        <id>jetty-run</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>jetty</name>
                <value>run</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <jetty.docroot>${project.build.directory}/jetty-docroot</jetty.docroot>
        </properties>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4.3</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>jetty-docroot</id>
                            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <outputDirectory>${jetty.docroot}</outputDirectory>
                                <resources>
                                    <resource>
                                        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp</directory>
                                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                                    </resource>
                                </resources>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <!-- for maven2, use org.eclipse.jetty for maven3 + slightly different configuration  -->
                    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <connectors>
                            <connector implementation="org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
                                <port>${jetty.port}</port>
                                <maxIdleTime>60000</maxIdleTime>
                            </connector>
                        </connectors>
                        <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
                        <contextPath>/${jetty.webcontext}</contextPath>
                        <webXml>${jetty.docroot}/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
                        <webAppSourceDirectory>${jetty.docroot}</webAppSourceDirectory>
                        <!-- maven3
                        <webApp>
                            <contextPath>/${jetty.webcontext}</contextPath>
                            <descriptor>${jetty.docroot}/WEB-INF/web.xml</descriptor>
                            <baseResource>${jetty.docroot}</baseResource>
                        </webApp>
                        -->
                        <systemProperties>
                            <systemProperty>
                                <name>java.awt.headless</name>
                                <value>true</value>
                            </systemProperty>
                        </systemProperties>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>jetty-run</id>
                            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>run</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
```